# Java spring jpa save all when isUpdated is true and not update removed rows

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

How to save all values ​​that are not updated by the user and deleted by the user.
My Post model

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Entity
@Table
public class Posts
{
    private int userId;
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String body;
    private boolean isUpdated = false;
    private boolean isDeleted = false;
}
```

PostDto

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class PostsDto {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String body;
}
```

and GetDataByRestTemplateAndSaveInDataBase

```
   public void getAndSaveToDataBase()
    {
        ResponseEntity<Object[]> responseEntity =
                restTemplate.getForEntity(BASE_URL, Object[].class);
        Object[] objects = responseEntity.getBody();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        List<Posts> collect = Arrays.stream(objects)
                .map(object -> mapper.convertValue(object, Posts.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        for(Posts posts:  collect)
        {
            if(!posts.isDeleted() || !posts.isUpdated())
            {
                //code
            }
        }
```

I have such idea ^^^. I think that exists better way for it. But i don't work with JPA

Comment: it has not got anything to do with JPA. you want to filter programmatically and then call saveAll() method of repository and you have to enable batches in JPA so that all entities are sent in batches instead of one by one.
You can filter while mapping object to Post entity, by using filter before collecting to list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest filtering the list using your criteria (Here isUpdated and isDeleted)

and you can pass that list directly to

```
yourRepository.saveAll(filteredlist);
```

Comment: I have info about isUpdate and isDelete in database. In Post model which I download don't have this info (default value). I must GetAll from dataBase firstly? It's not too expensive?

Comment: JPA work with ids if whatever you are trying to add and if that ids already exists.. instead of creating a new row in db it will update that existing row.  Second i recommend adding these two boolean field in model (ENTITY) .. It will take care all of your requirements

Comment: I have these two Boolean values ​​in the model (Post) but I don't want to update which are isUpdated or isRemoved "TRUE". isUpdated and isRemoved are created by me.

Comment: I download this Posts from other server by RestTemplate